# IIS cannot download zip file not being completed

Tags: iis, download, zip, iis-7.5

i'm trying to download zip file from my application hosted on IIS, but unfortunately the download is not being completed, it's stuck on 99%

i tried to change the MYME-Type to octet-stream, without luck. also i tired to manage the MYME-Type from the web.config with same situation.

NOTES: 1- I'm able to download RAR files without any issue.
       2- I'm using IIS 7.5 under windows server 2012

[image: Here the situation form Google Chrome, notting that i tried another browser and the IDM]

Answer (score 0):

According to your captured image, I guess you used chrome to download the file. There are two reason which will cause this issue.

One is your computer has installed the anti-virus checking for the downloaded files. I suggest you could try to disable the related setting and try again.

Besides, the chrome has contained the build-in scanning/checking the files which is used to checking the download files. I suggest you could try to start chrome with this switch:

```
--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection
```

Comment: the issues is not happening on chrome only (tried safari, firefox, .. ), the main concern is to download the file from a mobile app.  more over, on the server if i put localhost the download went normally but if i put the server ip i got the issues.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use postmand to download the zip file. I guess this may related with the browser setting.

Comment: it was an issues related to firewall.